# error : Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'

Tags: c#, winforms

I have opened `Resources.resx` file of a *WinForms application project* and copied images there. I am using the code shown below to get an image from the resources, but getting following error:

> Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'.

The error occurs in this line:

```
btn.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(test));
```

Relevant code:

```
private void genericButton_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    string test = "StudentModule.Properties.Resources" + btn.Name + ".png";

    //Getting the error here:
    btn.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(System
                                       .Reflection
                                       .Assembly
                                       .GetEntryAssembly()
                                       .GetManifestResourceStream(test));
}
```

The value of `test` is `"StudentModule.Properties.ResourcesbtnAbout.png"`, but I think it should be: `"StudentModule.Properties.Resources.btnAbout.png"`. I tried this line also but it's not working:

```
string test = "StudentModule.Properties.Resources." + btn.Name + ".png";
```

What is the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: tip #1: for string operations like this use string.Format("StudentModule.Properties.Resources.{0}.png",btn.Name)

Comment: I think your question title is misleading: It seems that `GetManifestResourceStream` returns `null` for you, so the actual issue to debug here is not why the `Bitmap` constructor throws an `ArgumentNullException`, but why the resource name you are requesting evaluates to `null`.

Comment: @Axarydax Thanks for the tip,but its still giving me same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GetManifestResourceStream() returns null when the stream could not be found.  Which will then bomb the Bitmap constructor.

So the string you used is wrong.  It isn't clear exactly how you embedded the resource.  Do strongly favor using the resource designer, Project + Resources tab.  Click the arrow on the Add Resource button, choose "Add Existing File" and select the file.  You can then use the ResourceManager to get the bitmap:

```
var imageName = "Chrysanthemum";
btn.BackgroundImage = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageName);
```

Note how the resource name is just the plain resource name as it appears in the resource designer.