# Editing custom SSIS PipelinComponent throws error "value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'"

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2013, bids

I created a custom `PipelineComponent` to convert data to Proper Case, like so:

```
[DtsPipelineComponent(DisplayName = "ProperCase")]
public class ProperCaseTransform : PipelineComponent
{
    //irrelevant code here
}
```

However, when I add this component to my data flow, and click "edit", I am met with with following error:

> Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'. (Microsoft Visual Studio)
>
> ---
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(Stream stream, Int32 width, Int32 height)
>     at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(Stream stream, Size size)
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.Common.ImageSourceHelper.GetIconFromResource(Assembly assembly, String resourceName, Boolean isLarge)
>      at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DesignUtils.ExtractManagedBitmap(String fileName, String resName, Boolean large)
>      at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DesignUtils.ExtractBitmap(String fileName, String iconResource, Boolean isNative, Boolean large)
>      at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.PipelineUtils.GetComponentIcon(IDTSComponentMetaData100 componentMetadata, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>      at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.FunctionLevelMappingUI..ctor(FunctionLevelComponentUI componentUI, IUserPromptService promptService)
>      at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.FunctionLevelComponentUI.EditImpl(IWin32Window parentControl)
>      at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DtsComponentUI.Edit(IWin32Window parentWindow, Variables variables, Connections connections)

I have seen similar problems happening with Visual Studio 2012 (apparently CU4 for SP1 fixes this), but never for VS 2013. How can I fix this issue? My component is unusable with editing.

Comment: I assume you've also seen the (sample code)[http://msftisprodsamples.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Katmai_August2008_RTM/Programming Samples/Data Flow/ChangeCase Component Sample/CS/ChangeCase/ChangeCase.cs]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was tipped off by this question: [error : Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19606194/1324019). Although this is clearly a bug in the IDE, it was possible to fix by adding an icon to my custom component:

```
[DtsPipelineComponent(DisplayName = "ProperCase", IconResource="MyNamespace.app.ico")]
public class ProperCaseTransform : PipelineComponent
{
    //irrelevant code here
}
```

I then included a random icon file in the dll (named app.ico), set the build action to "Embedded Resource", and recompiled; which fixed the issue in visual studio.

*NOTE:* the `IconResource` value has the format:

```
[ProjectNamespace] + "." + "Folder path separated by dots" + "." + "iconName.ico"
```

The project namespace is defined in the project properties.

Example: the icon `MyIcon.ico` in the folder icons in a project with namespace `MyProject` would have the icon resource value `"MyProject.Icons.MyIcon.ico"`